# How to further aggregate filtered data in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization

Here is how my input looks:

```
OrderDate | Company | ApprovalID | Amount |State,
2009-01-02 | A | AC | 200 | NY,
2009-01-05 | A | BT | 20000 | NY,
2009-01-04 | A | AC | 500 | CO,
2009-01-02 | B | XY | 2000 | TX,
2009-05-41 | B | XY | 30 | TX,
2009-04-21 | D | CR | 2222 | BR,
```

I am letting my user input a date range and company

```
                       tabPanel("Plot", fluid = TRUE,
                                sidebarLayout(
                                    sidebarPanel(id = 'sidebar',
                                        dateRangeInput("dateinput","Selects Dates",start = Sys.Date()-30,end = Sys.Date()),
                                                 selectInput("companyinput", "Select Comp", choices=choices1,multiple = TRUE,selected = NULL) 
                                                 ),
```

So if the user chooses dates between 2009-01-01 and 2009-01-31 and company A. I want to have a table that shows:

```
OrderDate | Company | ApprovalID | Amount |State ,
2009-01-02 | A | AC | 200 | NY ,
2009-01-05 | A | BT | 20000 | NY,
2009-01-04 | A | AC | 500 | CO,
```

```
   filtered <- reactive({
            if(is.null(input$companyinput)){
            bc3 %>%
                filter(as.Date(OrderDate) > input$dateinput[1],
                       as.Date(OrderDate) >= input$dateinput[2],
                )

                }
            else{
                bc3 %>%
                    filter(as.Date(OrderDate) > input$dateinput[1],
                           as.Date(OrderDate) >= input$dateinput[2],
                           CompanyNameID == input$companyinput
                    )
```

But then in the same dashboard I want to show different charts:

Further Aggregated at ApprovalID and Amount i.e. let us say a bar chart showing
AC spent 700 and BT spent 20000 (previous filters or order date and company intact)
then other chart
Aggregated at State and Amount i.e let us say a bar chart showing state and amount (once again order date and company that user has chosen)

Is there a way of doing so, or of storing the reactive input as dataframe so I can manipulate it as and how I want.

Thanks,
HV

Comment: Are you certain that `input$companyinput` will be `NULL`? If a `selectInput`, it should always be some string; if a user input, I still think it'll be a string, albeit potentially empty (`!nzchar(...)` might be useful here). However, I think your inequalities are wrong, don't you mean `>` and `<=`? Perhaps better for that whole `filtered` reactive could be `filter(bc3, between(as.Date(OrderDate), input$dateinput[1], input$dateinput[2]), !nzchar(input$companyinput) | input$companyinput == CompanyNameId)`.

Comment: (The times I *do* see a `NULL` in the inputs is during a shiny app's spool-up period, just a half second or so. When reactive blocks fire but the input widgets have not completely set up yet, they might be `NULL`. I think this was an impetus for `shiny::req`.)